# Centos 6 mouse stops periodically

Tags: mouse, centos

I have the following issue: I have a fresh Centos6 installation on a Lenovo Thinkpad W520 with X (Gnome) and when I move the mouse after 10-11 seconds it stops for half a second and then continues. In a CPU graph in this period of time I see that the CPUs jump up (all of them). Do you have any ideas on how to trace the problem back to the process causing this funny behavior? This behavior comes even on the login screen.
thanks

Comment: I suggest you to open a terminal with htop and look what is on the top of the list when the cpu activity is high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem. Switching the mouse helped. You never can rule that one out it seems. Then again I didn't have the CPU jump. Another possible solution might be switching to PS2 and see what happens.

Edit: Had the same error again, 1 year later - again it was a Logitech which failed.